# Проверка строки на присутствие числа

Tags: php, строки

Как проверить Строку на наличие целого числа ? Не используя регулярки и функцию ctype_digit.Не должно быть букв, точек и т.д в строке.

Comment: наличие целого числа или является ли строка целым?

Comment: Является ли строка целым числом. Без экспоненты 1e4,1.4 и так далее. Только цифры.

Comment: Простые регулярки не настолько медленные, как ими пугают. Но можно и тупо в лоб.

    function containsOnlyDigits($str)
    {
        for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($str); $i++) {
            if (intval($str[$i]) == 0 && $str[$i] !== '0') {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

Comment: @Etki, это как раз тот случай, когда `/^\d+$/` вполне к месту :) А вот непонятные ограничения (не использовать регулярки, не надевать рубашку с синими пуговицами etc) лучше послать лесом.

Comment: @Александр Черножуков, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 4):

**Убрал из ответа варианты с *is_numeric()* и *is_int()* - они не дают нужного результата***

Вариант с приведением типов и строгой проверкой:

```
if((integer)$foo === $foo || (string)((integer)$foo) === $foo)
```

Comment: Не подходит.Строку на наличие целого числа.Без каких либо символов, только цифры и все.

Comment: Предлагаю вместо strpos просто обернуть переменную в trim() перед проверкой

Comment: @Denis Khvorostin, споткнется на этом:  

    is_numeric('1e10')

Answer (score 0):

Первое, что пришло в голову:

```
<?php

$cases = array('1234567890', '1e10', '1.5');
$allowed_chars = range('0 ', '9 ');
for ($i = 0; $i < count($cases); ++$i) {
    $is_there_bad_symbols = false;
    $current_case = $cases[$i];
    for ($j = 0; $j < strlen($cases[$i]); ++$j) {
        $char = $current_case[$j];
        if (!in_array($char, $allowed_chars, true)) {
            $is_there_bad_symbols = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if ($is_there_bad_symbols) {
        echo $current_case . ' - test failed' . PHP_EOL;
    } else {
        echo $current_case . ' - test passed' . PHP_EOL;
    }   
}
```

---

```
1234567890 - test passed
1e10 - test failed
1.5 - test failed
```

---

Или коротко:

```
<?php

$allowed_chars = range('0 ', '9 ');
for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($string); ++$i) {
    $char = $string[$i];
    if (!in_array($char, $allowed_chars, true)) {
        $is_there_bad_symbols = true;
        break;
    }
}
echo $is_there_bad_symbols ? 'test failed' : 'test passed';
```